# Swift Turning Long Code Into Short Code

Tags: ios, swift

1.)I have these two functions that my team lead wants me to shorten using closures. I'm a new developer and can't figure out the right way to shorten these.

```
func sortUsers() {
    var sorted = [Member]()
    var sortedObjects = [PFObject]()

    for j in 0...2 {
        if member.count >  0 {
            for i in 0...member.count - 1 {
                if j == 0 {
                    if member[i].role == "OWNER" {
                        sorted.append(member[i])
                        sortedObjects.append(memberObject[i])
                    }
                } else if j == 1 {
                    if member[i].role == "ADMIN" {
                        sorted.append(member[i])
                        sortedObjects.append(memberObject[i])
                    }
                } else {
                    if member[i].role == "USER" {
                        sorted.append(member[i])
                        sortedObjects.append(memberObject[i])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    member = sorted
    memberObject = sortedObjects

}
```

Can almost be shortened by using this closure. `member.sort {$0.role < $1.role }` however it shorts alphabetically and that would be okay, but I need Owner to always be first.

2.)This second function I haven't figured anything out for. It has the way we had been doing it and then a closure in it that I tried replacing the longer method with but it didn't work.

```
    func filterUsers() {
    sortUsers()
    switch roleSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        filtered = member
        filteredObjects = memberObject
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 1:
        filtered = []
        filteredObjects = []
        for i in 0...member.count - 1 {
            if member[i].role == "OWNER" {
                filtered.append(member[i])
                filteredObjects.append(memberObject[i])
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 2:
      member.filter  { $0.role  == "ADMIN" }
       tableView.reloadData()
    case 3:
        filtered = []
        filteredObjects = []
        for i in 0...member.count - 1 {
            if member[i].role == "USER" {
                filtered.append(member[i])
                filteredObjects.append(memberObject[i])
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I greatly appreciate any help any kind soul may offer me :)

Comment: It's usually better to get feedback from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Comment: Unless you really have a problem or your code is terribly written. Reading your question again I'd say your code was not modular and perhaps it was OK to post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, create constants for `Role`, for example, using an `enum`:

```
enum Role : String {
    case owner = "OWNER"
    case admin = "ADMIN"
    case user = "USER"
}
```

Now let's declare ordering for roles:

```
extension Role : Comparable {
    var order: Int {
        switch self {
        case .owner:
            return 0
        case .admin:
            return 1
        case .user:
            return 2
        }
    }

    static func < (lhs: Role, rhs: Role) -> Bool {
        return lhs.order < rhs.order
    }
}
```

Let's suppose `Member` looks like this (note I have used my `Role` enum instead of your `String`).

```
class Member : CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var role: Role
    var name: String

    init(role: Role, name: String) {
        self.role = role
        self.name = name
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return self.name
    }
}

let members: [Member] = [
    Member(role: .user, name: "user1"),
    Member(role: .owner, name: "owner"),
    Member(role: .user, name: "user2"),
    Member(role: .admin, name: "admin2"),
    Member(role: .admin, name: "admin2"),
]
```

Now your sorting can be reduced to:

```
let sortedMembers = members.sorted { $0.role < $1.role }
```

To sort both arrays together, we can, for example, create pairs member-object and sort those pairs:

```
let pairs = zip(members, objects)
let sortedPairs = pairs.sorted { $0.0.role < $1.0.role }

let sortedMembers = sortedPairs.map { $0.0 }
let sortedObjects = sortedPairs.map { $0.1 }
```

To get the filtered objects, let's simplify again using roles:

```
if roleSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { // all selected
     filtered = member
     filteredObjects = memberObject
     tableView.reloadData()
     return
}

let roles: [Role] = [.owner, .admin, .user]
let role = roles[roleSelector.selectedSegmentIndex - 1]

filtered = members.filter { $0.role == role }

tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Don't you also need to implement the equatable protocol? or that doesn't apply to enums?

Comment: ^^ reasons i love swift

Comment: @Honey Enums without associated values automatically synthesise conformance to `Hashable` (and therefore also `Equatable`).

Comment: @Hamish hmmm. I just wrote an enum with an associated type of `Int`. By using `!=` on two enums I was able to verify that it does conform to Equatable, yet it *didn't* conform to comparable even though `Int` (its associated type *does*. Does that mean your comment was incorrect?

Comment: @Honey You mean a *raw value* of type `Int`? My comment was correct as I said `Hashable` (which only requires the `hashValue` property + `Equatable` conformance), not `Comparable`. The compiler doesn't automatically synthesise a `Comparable` conformance as you may not want it to just compare the raw values (such as in this very case).

Comment: @Hamish oh yes. Reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) you were correct

Comment: on segment `0` you need `filtered = sortedMember filteredObjects = sortedObject`

Comment: on the other segments you also need to zip it with the sortedObjects and filter this pairs: `let sortedPairs = zip(sortedMembers, sortedObjects); let filteredPairs = sortedPairs.filter { $0.0.role role }; filtered = filteredPairs.map { $0.0 }; filteredObjects = filteredPairs.map { $0.1 }`

Comment: to make it more easy i would add the PFObject to the Member Struct: `class Member{ var role: Role; var name: String; var object: PFObject; }`

Comment: remove the `;` of my comments to write it in each line

Comment: @RileyOsborne if this answer of `Sulhan` helps you with your question then accept it as answer (click on the gray checkmark on the left side of the answer)